# Android toolbar custom layout clickable icon with selector animated background

Tags: android, animation, button, toolbar

I am trying to give clicked effect to imageview placed in custom layout inside toolbar. So I have implemented it like this:

this is included inside toolbar:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/img_tool_back"
        style="@style/SelectorLayout"
        >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_grey_600_24dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
.
. //Other action buttons
.
</Linearlayout>
```

Selector layout style has:

```
<style name="SelectorLayout">
    <item name="android:layout_width">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_action</item>
</style>
```

and animated action selector is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">
<item android:drawable="@color/colorGray" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/colorGray" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/colorGray" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

I was wondering if it was possible to have same effect with using just one single imageview? instead of using imageview inside linear layout?

Answer (score 1):

Acutely, you can define different drawables with your image and different backgrounds, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <size
                android:width="24dp"
                android:height="24dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorGrey" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@android:drawable/ic_arrow_back_grey_600_24dp" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then apply this in the `selector_action.xml`.
Finally, Use a `ImageButton` with `android:background="@drawable/selector_action"` instead of `ImageView`.

Hope it helps.